# Unable to find dynamically created control when JSON is used

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, asynchronous

I am calling JSON method on selected index changed of the drop down list which is as follows

```
function StepImplementationScript(SelectedValue,UniqueField) {
     debugger;
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "DynamicForm.aspx/StepImplementationScript",
         data: "{strSelectedValue: " + SelectedValue + ", strUniqueField: '" + UniqueField + "' }",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         async: true,
         cache: false,
         success: function(response) {
             alert("OnSuccess" + response.d);
             if (msg) {
                 msg.close();
             }
         },
         error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
             alert(jqXHR.responseText);
         },

         failure: function(response) {
             //alert("Onfailure" + response.d);          
         }
     });
    }
```

In this 'StepImplementationScript' method of server side when i try to find dynamically created control, the controls are not getting find and coming as null.

Selected change event i have written in Jquery through which i have called the JSON method.

This is the same page (DynamicForm.aspx) on which controls are created dynamically.

Why this is so ? and how should i resolve this issue ???

Comment: Are SelectedValue and UniqueField null when you call the ajax method, or just at DynamicForm.aspx/StepImplementationScript?

Comment: NO, values are available... Because i am doing some data filtration on data table with help of these values and after that trying to find controls.

Comment: *When* are you invoking the above client-side script? Have the controls been loaded in the DOM?

Comment: yes, they are surely loaded in DOM